# I would like to minus an Hour within VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have added a snippet of my code below. I am importing a file that gets generated every 2 hour. due to the time it started i need to minus an hour and add that to the file name to import the file. for example:

> file name_"mm"(month)*"dd"(day)*"hh"(hour).txt

the hour needs to be including the leading 0 as well.

```
Dim hour As String
Dim day As String
Dim month As String
Dim project As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("MQL_RAW")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("BOM")


file_name = Sheets("Master").Range("F" & rep1).Value
file_name2 = Sheets("Master").Range("G" & rep1).Value
output_sheet = Sheets("Master").Range("L" & rep1).Value
row_number = Sheets("Master").Range("M" & rep1).Value
hour = Format(Time, "Hh") - Time(1, 0, 0)
day = Format(Date, "Dd")
month = Format(Date, "Mm")
project = Sheets("Master").Range("B2").Value

LastRow = Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Activate
Columns("A:A").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

ws.Activate

aa = file_name2 & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Time, "Hh")

With Sheets(output_sheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + file_name +   "\" + month + "\" + day + "\" + file_name2 & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" &   hour & ".txt", Destination:=Sheets(output_sheet).Range("$A$" + row_number))
    '.Name = file_name & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & Format(Time, "Hh")
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
filename = "name_" & Format(Now - TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), "MMDDHH") & ".txt"
```

---

Alternatively, use something like:

```
Dim reportStart As Date
reportStart = Now
```

at the start of your code, and then when it comes to saving it at the end, just use:

```
filename = "name_" & Format(reportStart, "MMDDHH") & ".txt"
```

Comment: can i just use `reportStart, "HH"`? I have also got the correct hour in a cell within a sheet that the vba can link to but the reason i do no use that is the leading 0 gets ignored when the VBA looks at the cell contents no matter what i do. so if that can be hardcoded to include the leading 0 within VBA that would be a lot easier. I have changed the format of the cell to show the leading 0 but that makes no difference within VBA

Comment: **1.** Yes **2.** You need to format the value in VBA, not on the worksheet - if the hour is in A1, then you would use `Format(Range("A1").Value, "00")`

Comment: first of all thank you for the quick responses. I have tried that code and implimented it in my code and i get an error `hour = Sheets("Master").Range("I" & rep1).Value
Format(Range("I10")).Value , "00"` that is the code and i get the following error **object required**. Sorry if im being a noob

Comment: `hour = Format(Sheets("Master").Range("I" & rep1).Value, "00")`